# Do I have to replace the Google+ API

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js, google-plus

I use Passport.js and passport-google-oauth20. which means using Google + API. but I got an email from Google that the Google + API will be shutdown.

**UPDATE**

from passport.js  http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/

> Configuration The Client Id and Client Secret needed to authenticate
>   with Google can be set up from the Google Developers Console. You may
>   also need to enable Google+ API in the developer console, otherwise
>   user profile data may not be fetched. Google supports authentication
>   with both oAuth 1.0 and oAuth 2.0.

I get a message :

> On March 7, 2019, we are shutting down the legacy Google+ APIs. This
>   has been a progressive shutdown where calls to affected APIs began
>   intermittently failing on January 28, 2019.

So what should I do? can I no longer use passport.js?

Comment: I would contact the developers on that project and ask them what they intend to do.

Comment: tell me when you get something @DaImTo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is going to shut down Google+ in some time so you wont be able to use Google+ APIs anymore. I dont think you can do much about it. You can remove support of Google+ from you application.

Here is the link - https://www.theverge.com/2018/12/10/18134541/google-plus-privacy-api-data-leak-developers

As per my understanding, you can still use passport-google-oauth2 for google authentication since this is associated with google account not with google+ account.

Your google+ APIs will not work anymore. You can get that information here - https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown

Now about your question regarding using passport.js, you should be able to use passport.js but you will not be able to call only google+ APIs. You can use all the other google APIs from using passport.js

Comment: i update my question, there is a message like this: `You may also need to enable Google+ API in the developer console`.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you have an issue like this with an opensource project the best course of action is to always check their issue forum.

There is currently an open issue up on passport.js git project [713](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/713)

If you check the issue there are several ideas for fixes and it includes a pull request for a potential fix using which uses the userinfo endpoint instead of using the Google+ api

[fix: handle new userinfo endpoint](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2/pull/51)